# Load and display local images alongside API data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Link to codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-cannon-yz2m4?file=/src/pages/home/sections/CategorySection.tsx). Disclaimer - it loads another environment which I'm not working on. In order to see the environment live for what I'm working on, locally I run 'npm run start:bfe' and it works. However Codesandbox defaults to the other environment live in the browser.

---

On line 265 in the getLink function, which grabs the API data, I’ve added a ‘groupImage?: string’ typescript value to pass the array of local category images in as an argument - to load with the API data.

```
const getLink = (
        groupCode: string,
        groupDisplayName: string,
        groupCount?: number,
        groupImage?: string
      )
```

Then on line 300, I’ve made an array (‘categoryImages’) that holds all of the category images, which I've imported at the top of the React component.

```
// Grouped category images array
      const categoryImages = [
        attachmentImage,
        compactorImage,
        telehandlerImage,
        backhoeLoaderImage,
        excavatorImage,
        wheelLoaderImage,
        compactTrackLoaderImage,
        skidSteerLoaderImage
      ];
```

Then finally on line 338, I’ve added categoryImages array to the newLink variable that alongside the API values, which will be pushed to render out on the page. Everything from the API renders out to the page, except the local images I'm trying to load in alongside the API data.

```
} else if (Constants.isEnvironmentBFE) {
          count++;
          const newLink = getLink(
            // Grabbing API values
            group["group-code"], // <-- this loads
            group["group-display-name"], <-- this loads
            group.count <-- this loads
            // Local images
            // categoryImages <-- this doesn't. This isn't from the API, it's the local images stored in an array.
          );
          categoryList[column].push(newLink);
          endColumnCheck(count);
        }
```

Finally, render it to the page.

```
          <div id="mainProdFamList" className={fadeInClass}>
            {isEnvironmentBFE ? (
              <>
                <div className="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                  {categoryList[0].length > 0
                    ? // Load live content, where I want images to display
                      categoryList[0]
                    : // Content before API is loaded - images do display here briefly until the API loads
                      getDefaultLinks()[0]}
                </div>
                <div className="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                  {categoryList[1].length > 0
                    ? / Load live content, where I want images to display
                      categoryList[1]
                    : // Content before API is loaded - images do display here briefly until the API loads
                      getDefaultLinks()[1]}
                </div>
              </>
            )}
          </div>
          <div className="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're passing an array rather than a string (Assuming it's only commented to demonstrate it didn't work when uncommented).

From what I understand briefly looking at it, you should be passing categoryImages[column] instead of categoryImages?

Edit:
I've had more time to have a proper look.
At line 318 there is the following if statement:

```
if (
  Constants.isEnvironmentBFE || //BFE - show all
  isHeavyEquipmentCategory(group) //TCAT - heavy equipment only
)
```

As your environment is BFE, the code in that block is running rather than the code with the categoryImages.

Now, there's not a proper way to identify which image to use for what other than them being in the same order (currently). If a new group is added this would be difficult to maintain.

I would replace your categoryImages definition with the following:

```
const categoryImages = {
  "Work Tools - Outils De Travail": attachmentImage,
  "Compactors - Compacteurs": compactorImage,
  "Telehandlers - Chargeurs À Bras Télescopique": telehandlerImage,
  "Backhoe Loaders - Chargeuses-pelleteuses": backhoeLoaderImage,
  "Excavators - Pelles Hydrauliques": excavatorImage,
  "Wheel Loaders / Integrated Toolcarriers - Chargeurs Sur Pneus / Chargeurs Industriels": wheelLoaderImage,
  "COMPACT TRACK LOADER - COMPACT TRACK LOADER": compactTrackLoaderImage,
  "Skid Steer Loaders / ASV - Chargeurs Compacts rigides": skidSteerLoaderImage
};
```

And then your new link code becomes:

```
const newLink = getLink(
  group["group-code"],
  group["group-display-name"],
  group.count,
  categoryImages[group["group-code"]]
);
```

You could swap out the group codes for a different identifier if necessary.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @dcof! 

I've implemented the code and the images still won't show :( I think it may be because the '["group-code"]' part of 'categoryImages[group["group-code"]]' is referring to an API value, when in reality we're trying to load in local images?

Comment: See this fork of your codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-khorana-v5ynw?file=/src/pages/home/sections/CategorySection.tsx
I've modified it to load the environment correctly, and applied the fix to CategorySection.tsx as described above.